# css set size relative to page inside div

Tags: css, image, width

I have a code like this;

```
<div>
    <img style="max-width:90%" src="..." />
</div>
```

Which results in a `div` with the size of the original image, and the image being pressed together.
So, if the original image width was 100 pixels, the displayed image is only 90 pixels wide.

I know why it happens; setting the css with a % will refer to the parenting block's width.
What I want to know is; **how do I make it refer to the page**, instead of to the div?

My solution would be making JavaScript which would check the page width, and set the width in pixels (after calculating what 90% of the page width is)... but I'd guess it ought to be easier.

**Edit:** for the record, this would be my JS solution;

```
<script>
    var maxw = 0.5*screen.availWidth;
    var maxh = 0.5*screen.availHeight;

    document.write('<style type="text/css">#lightboxImage { max-width:' + maxw + 'px; max-height: '+maxh+'px; } </style>');
</script>
```

Comment: you may try position:absolute;

Comment: If you have a absolute width value declared for a container higher up in the document tree, then your percentage is relative to this.

Comment: @DamnYankee: Please, when you want to include **blocks of code** in your answer, indent every line of code by four spaces; instead of using `'`. Thanks!

Comment: One question: are you trying to make the image element overflow the div?

Comment: @Pedro; nope, I have not set a width for the div. It scales along with the image. My problem is, that it defaults it's size to the unscaled size of the image.  @aleksv; didn't work

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to do this with or without javascript

Comment: Is this what you say it's happening? http://jsfiddle.net/Lc6Yk/3/

Comment: @Sydenam; I'm trying without, but I wanted to show the current situation. @Pedro; yes, that's it @everyone; I think I'll just stick with my JS, which works. I was just hoping for some hidden feature of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:100%;">
<img src="http://www.website.com/image.jpg" style="max-width:50%;/>
</div>
```

If you set the size of the containing div to `100%` then the `max-width:` of your image will calculate `50%` of the whole page.

You can `float` the containing div or use `position:absolute` to place it where you like and take it out of the flow of the page (so it doesn't push all of your content out of its way)